# https and www not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

As I tried so many things to redirect www to non-www of subdomain via htaccess but not going well

I want to like this

**https://test.example.com**

but while I write like this

**https://www.test.example.com**

then the webpage gives me error like this

> **"Your connection is not private"**

i tried this code in htaccess but not working properly

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

this code only redirects if i didnot mention **https** in **www.test.example.com**

Comment: Your connection is not private most likely means you have a problem with your certificate. Is it a self signed certificate or one issued by a CA (in which case test.example.com wouldn't be the real domain right?

Comment: @Juan i purchased wildcard SSL certificate for subdomains

Answer (score 0):

To redirect everything to htpps I use the following. It is at the top of the .htaccess.

I have added your two lines for redirecting from www to the domain after the forwarding to https, and changed the HOST_HTTP to HOST_HTTPS.

Please note I haven't tried it.

Perhaps you can remove this if it doesn't apply:  `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you share the real url so as to connect and see the certificate?